# Making to a page if file exists on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a url/file like example.com/siteuploads/thumb/c/1234_0.jpg, example.com/siteuploads/thumb/c/1234_1.jpg and so on.

I want if image have id 0 mean like the first URL then it should redirect to homepage.

My .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(siteuploads/thumb/c/)([0-9]_0)\.jpg$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Please dont post your code as image, post it as text.

Comment: I was trying it to post as text but due to stackoverflow rules it need to be indented by 4 spaces and I tried to do that but it still keep showing me the same error so I had to remove it and post as an image. I am using mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(siteuploads/thumb/c/)([0-9]{1,8}_0)\.jpg$ / [R=301,L]
```

You can test this code [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134848/discussion-on-answer-by-stas-making-to-a-page-if-file-exists-on-server).